# wifi-direct disabled in my phone (4.0.3)

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

The android version of my phone is 4.0.3, and apps I build with 4.0.3 api can run on this phone. However, when I try to run the wifi direct sample, the app keeps reminding me to 'enable P2P from action bar button above or system settings'. But there is no such "P2P setting" on my phone so somehow I probably can't use the wifi direct. Btw, wifi supports b/g/n. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The P2P feature maybe 'hidden'
In Settings > Wi-Fi settings hit option key to display Wi-Fi Direct

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say this but it depends on your phone and its integration of ICS.

For example, I have two devices that are both running 4.03 the motorola razr maxx and the samsung galaxy IIIs.  The razr maxx does not have a setting for Wifi-Direct. Although, the razr maxx does surface adhoc P2P network connections through the standard wifi manager and settings.  The samsung galaxy IIIs does have Wifi-Direct settings but seems to have more trouble with legacy adhoc networks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even i was facing the same issue. I have two tablets one is Sony Tablet S and the other one is Samsung Galaxy II - both are running on ICS 4.0.3. Here is what i found browsing through the internet. Wifi Direct P2P works in Samsung but not in Sony.

> It depends on which wifi chip the device use. As I known, Broadcom
>   bcm4329/4330 , Atheros 6005, and Ti 1281 can support this feature on
>   ICS. But, you need porting the suitable driver and firmware for wifi
>   direct.